# Check Numeric vs. Non-numeric column type in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, information-schema

I'm working with MySQL's INFORMATION_SCHEMA schema to automate some processing on generic columns in tables.
One task is to identify numeric and non-numeric column types to apply specific operations in the two cases.
Of course I can define operations for each single data type in MySQL and solve my issue that way, but I'm wondering whether using a solution like:

```
SELECT
    NUMERIC_PRECISION
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
    TABLE_SCHEMA='aschema' AND 
    TABLE_NAME='atable' AND
    COLUMN_NAME='acolumn'
```

when transversing tables and columns could be good enough to have a rough separation between the two kind of columns I'm interested in.
My goal would be having a TRUE/FALSE identifying a column to contain numeric data type or not.
Any other idea is welcome.
Drawbacks point-out is welcome too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I vote for `NUMERIC_PRECISION IS NOT NULL`.  It includes "bit".  To exclude "bit", use `NUMERIC_SCALE IS NOT NULL`.  If you want to argue that "enum" or "year" are numeric, then go with an IN-clause like Dudi's.

Comment: I've chosen this answer because it's more in-line with my needs. But @Dudi one is not to discard (only I cannot accept both).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [COLUMN_NAME],[DATA_TYPE] FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE [DATA_TYPE] IN ('int','bigint','smallint','mediumint' 'tinyint','float','numeric')
```

Comment: ok, this is like my defining operations on single data and I don't like it so much because it is based on enumerating the types...which can be troublesome, e.g. it exists also `mediumint` (I'll add after commenting), so you have to maintain the list while working... [BTW I'll try re-wording the question to clear up]